# Jquery dialog confimation before ajax post to a controller + asp .net mvc3 + c#

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, confirmation

I have a toggle button which works perfectly. The javascript and view is below:

jQuery:

```
$('.list-delist-link').delegate("a", "click", function (e) {
    var obj = $(this);
    if ($(this).hasClass('delist-property')) {
        // Post to controller
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        // Post to controller
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

View:

```
<div class="list-delist-link">
    @if(item.IsPropertyDisabled) {
        @Html.ActionLink("List", "Enable", "Property", new { id = item.PropertyId }, new { @class="list-property other-button" })
    } else {
        @Html.ActionLink("Delist", "Disable", "Property", new { id = item.PropertyId }, new { @class="delist-property other-button" })
    }
</div>
```

However, now I want to add a confirmation dialog box before the ajax action. However, everything breaks up when I am try to do that ... I am not sure why. I have the jQuery and css files on the layout page

The changes I made are listed below:

Changes to jQUery:

```
var obj;
$('.list-delist-link').delegate("a", "click", function (e) {
     obj = $(this);
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog(open):
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Additional jQuery for modal confirmation:

```
$(function() {        
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({            
        resizable: false, height:140, modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Delete all items": function() {
                if (obj.hasClass('delist-property')) {
                    // Post to controller
                } else {
                    // Post to controller
                }
                $(this).dialog("close");                
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }            
        }
    });    
});
```

Additional div in View:

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Are you sure?">   
        <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>These items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>
</div>
```

Can you please tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You must add  `autoOpen: false`, look this

```
$( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({  
        autoOpen : false,  
        resizable: false, height:140, modal: true,
        buttons: {......
```

Comment: I will try that but I dont think that is the issue because the link does not even go to jQuery ... and it directly goes to the page and gets a 404 error as it can only be accessed via POST action. I have even tried to put an alert in the delegate click but the click does not go in jQuery ... any idea?

Comment: `$("#dialog-confirm").dialog(open)` use the `dialog("open")`

Comment: and use `@Ajax.ActionLink` instead of `@Html.ActionLink`